# Android memory leaks understanding

Tags: android, list, memory-leaks, android-activity

I am reading the book called ["Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) and there is a piece of code which leads to memory leaks.

```
public class Stack {
 private Object[] elements;
 private int size = 0;
 private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

public Stack() {
    elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
}

public void push(Object e) {
    ensureCapacity();
    elements[size++] = e;
}

public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return elements[--size];
}

/**
 * Ensure space for at least one more element, roughly
 * doubling the capacity each time the array needs to grow.
 */
private void ensureCapacity() {
    if (elements.length == size)
        elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
}
```

}

The `pop` method should be replaced with

```
public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    Object result = elements[--size];
    elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
    return result;
}
```

It's clear to me. Can the code (see below) lead to memory leaks? E.g., I rotate the screen a lot of times and `private ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(CAPASITY);` allocates memory each time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int CAPASITY = 10000;
    private ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(CAPASITY);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Some work on mArrayList
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Some work on mArrayList
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO: mArrayList = null to prevent memory leaks. Is it necessary to do it?
    }

}
```

Comment: in which way does it leak?

Comment: @blackbelt, I edited the question. E.g., memory is allocated after each screen rotation.

Comment: @RedPlanet, there's no memory leaks, mArrayList will contain references for new ArrayList, and there will be no references to old one, so it will be garbage collected. Sorry for offtopic, did you read the second edition? Where did you get it in Moscow and what cost it had?

Comment: @SpongeBobFan, I've been reading for a couple of weeks. Are there any better editions? I don't remember where I bought it.

Comment: @RedPlanet, there's 1st edition translated to Russian, and 2nd edition that isn't. 2nd edition is much more up-to-date (2008 vs 2001), but i saw it only in 1 internet shop for $200 with 21 days for delivery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // TODO: mArrayList = null to prevent memory leaks. Is it necessary to do it?

No, the activity object and its members such as `mArrayList` can be garbage collected. Your activity code does not show anything that would hold object references unnecessarily long.